# ERR! TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, storybook

Showing Error storybook start on compile SCSS
When the problem is when I `npm run storybook-start` command shows some error. it's shown after updating `"sass-loader": "^7.1.0" : "sass-loader": "^13.2.2"` and `"css-loader": "^3.0.0" : "css-loader": "^6.5.1"` this packages.
can anyone solve/provide any solutions plz?

Error log:
npm run storybook

```
> aem-maven-archetype@1.0.0 storybook
> concurrently --kill-others "npm run storybook-files-watch" "npm run storybook-start" "gulp"

[0] 
[0] > aem-maven-archetype@1.0.0 storybook-files-watch
[0] > webpack --watch --config ./webpack.prod.js && clientlib --verbose
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > aem-maven-archetype@1.0.0 storybook-start
[1] > start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./dist
[1] 
[2] [18:49:18] Using gulpfile ~/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/gulpfile.js
[2] [18:49:18] Starting 'default'...
[1] info @storybook/react v6.5.16
[1] info 
[1] (node:50255) DeprecationWarning: --static-dir CLI flag is deprecated, see:
[1] 
[1] https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated---static-dir-cli-flag
[1] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1] info => Loading presets
[1] info Found existing addon "@storybook/addon-docs", skipping.
[1] WARN   Failed to load preset: {"type":"presets"} on level 1
[1] ERR! TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
[1] ERR!     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
[1] ERR!     at validateString (node:internal/validators:161:11)
[1] ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1014:3)
[1] ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
[1] ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:178:16)
[1] ERR!     at getContent (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:194:10)
[1] ERR!     at loadPreset (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:203:20)
[1] ERR!     at /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:256:18
[1] ERR!     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
[1] ERR!     at loadPresets (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:255:18)
[1] ERR!  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
[1] ERR!     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
[1] ERR!     at validateString (node:internal/validators:161:11)
[1] ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1014:3)
[1] ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
[1] ERR!     at interopRequireDefault (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:178:16)
[1] ERR!     at getContent (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:194:10)
[1] ERR!     at loadPreset (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:203:20)
[1] ERR!     at /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:256:18
[1] ERR!     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
[1] ERR!     at loadPresets (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/cjs/presets.js:255:18) {
ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
[1] ERR! }
[1] info => Serving static files from ././dist at /
[1] info Addon-docs: using MDX1
[1] info => Using implicit CSS loaders
[1] (node:50255) DeprecationWarning: Default PostCSS plugins are deprecated. When switching to '@storybook/addon-postcss',
[1] you will need to add your own plugins, such as 'postcss-flexbugs-fixes' and 'autoprefixer'.
[1] 
[1] See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-default-postcss-plugins for details.
[1] WARN Storybook support for Create React App is now a separate preset.
[1] WARN To use the new preset, install `@storybook/preset-create-react-app` and add it to the list of `addons` in your `.storybook/main.js` config file.
[1] WARN The built-in preset has been disabled in Storybook 6.0.
[1] info => Using default Webpack4 setup
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 0% compiling
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/0 modules 0 active 
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/1 modules 1 active multi /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/storybook-init-framework-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/docs/config-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@whitespace/storybook-addon-html/dist/esm/preset/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/generated-stories-entry.js
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active 
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/2 modules 1 active /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/3 modules 2 active /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/4 modules 3 active /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/5 modules 4 active /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/6 modules 5 active /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
[1] <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/7 modules 6 active /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
[1] node:internal/crypto/hash:71
[1]   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
[1]                   ^
[1] 
[1] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[1]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[1]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
[1]     at module.exports (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
[1]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
[1]     at handleParseError (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
[1]     at /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
[1]     at /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
[1]     at /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
[1]     at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
[1]     at /Users/bs1006/Work/Abbvie/abbvie-ous-awcm-sitegenerator/ui.frontend/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4 {
[1]   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
[1]   library: 'digital envelope routines',
[1]   reason: 'unsupported',
[1]   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
[1] }
[1] 
[1] Node.js v18.9.0
[1] npm run storybook-start exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[2] gulp exited with code SIGTERM
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] npm run storybook-files-watch exited with code SIGTERM
```

main.js config

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],

  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-docs",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-scss",
    '@whitespace/storybook-addon-html',
    'storybook-addon-designs'
  ],

  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

pakage.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "storybook-start": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./dist",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.20.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.20.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.3",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.3",
    "@types/babel__traverse": "7.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
    "acorn": "^8.7.1",
    "aem-clientlib-generator": "^1.4.3",
    "aemsync": "^4.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
    "browserslist": "^4.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.12",
    "glob-import-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "storybook-addon-designs": "^6.2.1",
    "storybook-figma": "^0.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.1",
    "suneditor": "^2.39.0",
    "suneditor-react": "^3.1.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "watch": "^1.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.9",
    "@whitespace/storybook-addon-html": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2"
  },
```